# "Null" is printed when I try to print out the array's value in java program

Tags: java, arrays, loops, 2d

My problem is that when I want to print out any element of my 2D array the Null is shown instead of the array's element value. 
How may I solve the problem? and why I get this output despite my array has members? (I am new to programming)

I tried to just print out one array member by writing the element number directly but still, there is some problem so the random numbers are not the problem. 
I have also tried to define a new array inside the pickCard() method in order to copy the cardList array to it but it did not help either.

I have 2 different classes, the first class is called **Tutorial** and it includes the **main()** method and the other is called **Kortlek** and all my codes are there.

This is the Tutorial class

```
package tutorial;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Tutorial {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // Using Scanner class to get in the input from user
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        // We initialize our class Kortlek
        Kortlek newKortlek = new Kortlek();

        // Here we choose a nickname for user: 
        System.out.print("Please choose a name: ");
        String Username = input.next();
        String pcName = newKortlek.nickNamePC();


        String userAnswer;
        int userScore = 1;
        int pcScore = 2;
        do {
            System.out.println("You picked up: " + newKortlek.pickCard());
            System.out.println(pcName + " has picked up: "  + newKortlek.pickCard());
            System.out.println("Do you want to continue? write yes or no");
            userAnswer = input.next();

        } while (!userAnswer.equals("no"));
       System.out.println("Your score is: " + userScore);
       System.out.println(pcName + "'s score is: " + pcScore);
    }
}
```

This is the Kortlek class

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

package tutorial;

import java.util.Random;

/**
 *
 * @author hezarehee
 */
public class Kortlek {

    Random r = new Random();
    /**
     * In this method we create 2D array in order to group each card color and its cards (1-13)
     */
    String cardList[][] = new String[3][12];

    public String[][] buildCardGame () {
        String[] farg = {"Spader", "Hjarter", "Ruter", "Klover"};
        String[] nummer = {"1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "Jack", "Queen", "Ace"};


        for (int i=0; i < farg.length; i++) {
            for (int j=0; j < nummer.length; j++) {
                cardList[i][j] = farg[i] + " " + nummer[j];
            }

        }
        return cardList;
    }

    /**
     * Here we make a method that let computer to choose a name from given names in array
     */
    public String nickNamePC () {
        String[] nickName = {"Daivd", "Rahim", "Michael", "Sara", "Marie", "Jenny"};

        int low = 0; 
        int high = 5; 
        int result =  r.nextInt(high-low) + low;
        String chosenName = nickName[result];
        return chosenName;
    }

    /**
     * Here we each time pick up a card from our 2D Array cardList[][] 
     */
    public String pickCard() {
        int takeColor = r.nextInt(3-1) + 1;
        int takeNumber = r.nextInt(12-1) + 1;

        // we put our random numbers into the array carDList
        String pickedCard = cardList[takeColor][takeNumber];
        return pickedCard;
    }

}
```

I need to make a card game (Rank and colors), in this game the users play against the program, first in the array cardList, I tried to create 52 different cards for in 4 groups (Clubs, Diamonds, Hearts, Spades). I made the array inside method called buildCardGame().

By method pickCard(), I try to pick a random card by adding 2 random numbers from 0-3 for the color and 0-12 for the rank. 
But when I print it out so I get null.

Comment: most likely, you call it before initializing the members

Comment: change `String cardList[][] = new String[3][12]` to String cardList[][] = new String[4][13];

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### First, You need to modify where `cardlist` is initialized.

```java
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

package tutorial;

import java.util.Random;

/**
 *
 * @author hezarehee
 */
public class Kortlek {

    Random r = new Random();
    /**
     * In this method we create 2D array in order to group each card color and its cards (1-13)
     */
    String cardList[][] = new String[4][13];

    // ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
    // String cardList[][] = new String[3][12];

    public String[][] buildCardGame () {
        String[] farg = {"Spader", "Hjarter", "Ruter", "Klover"};
        String[] nummer = {"1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "Jack", "Queen", "Ace"};


        for (int i=0; i < farg.length; i++) {
            for (int j=0; j < nummer.length; j++) {
                cardList[i][j] = farg[i] + " " + nummer[j];
            }

        }
        return cardList;
    }

    /**
     * Here we make a method that let computer to choose a name from given names in array
     */
    public String nickNamePC () {
        String[] nickName = {"Daivd", "Rahim", "Michael", "Sara", "Marie", "Jenny"};

        int low = 0;
        int high = 5;
        int result =  r.nextInt(high-low) + low;
        String chosenName = nickName[result];
        return chosenName;
    }

    /**
     * Here we each time pick up a card from our 2D Array cardList[][] 
     */
    public String pickCard() {
        int takeColor = r.nextInt(3-1) + 1;
        int takeNumber = r.nextInt(12-1) + 1;

        // we put our random numbers into the array carDList
        String pickedCard = cardList[takeColor][takeNumber];
        return pickedCard;
    }

}
```

#### Second, `buildCardGame` method must be called

```java
package tutorial;

// import java.util.Arrays; // not used
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Tutorial {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // Using Scanner class to get in the input from user
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        // We initialize our class Kortlek
        Kortlek newKortlek = new Kortlek();

        // initialize the members
        newKortlek.buildCardGame(); 

        // Here we choose a nickname for user:
        System.out.print("Please choose a name: ");
        String Username = input.next();
        String pcName = newKortlek.nickNamePC();


        String userAnswer;
        int userScore = 1;
        int pcScore = 2;
        do {
            System.out.println("You picked up: " + newKortlek.pickCard());
            System.out.println(pcName + " has picked up: "  + newKortlek.pickCard());
            System.out.println("Do you want to continue? write yes or no");
            userAnswer = input.next();

        } while (!userAnswer.equals("no"));
        System.out.println("Your score is: " + userScore);
        System.out.println(pcName + "'s score is: " + pcScore);
    }
}
```